# why new websites are using .io domain these days?

Tags: dns, angular, startup, github-pages

A number of startups and technology websites are using .io domain these days in lieu of .com or .org; Is there any specific reason for that ?
Like:

```
github.io
mean.io
angular.io
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question belongs more to http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/ or any site about computer general questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[.io is the Top Level Domain for British Indian Ocean Territory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.io).

But **io** has another meaning for geeks :

> In computing, input/output or I/O (or, informally, io or IO) is the communication between an information processing system, such as a computer, and the outside world, possibly a human or another information processing system. [*See full article on Wikipedia*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Input/output).

So this is geek hype !